# How python's standard library functions are called without creating an object?

Tags: python, class, object

In below example, the object of random is not created

```
from random import randint

print(randint(0, 10))
```

the definition of the randint function is as follow

```
import _random

class Random(_random.Random):
     def randint(self, a, b):
        return self.randrange(a, b+1)
```

Now in my case:

```
class XYZ:
     def func(self):
         do something
```

to call func, I have to create object of XYZ and then call function `XYZ().func()`else it throws error...

But I want to do it like

```
XYZ.func()
```

simply like how standard library function works. is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`random` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py) defines an instance of `Random` at the module level:

```
# Line 786
_inst = Random()
```

and `random.randint` is just a reference to a bound method for that instance:

```
# Line 791
randint = _inst.randint
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

```
class XYZ:
     def func(self):
         do something
```

You want this:

```
class XYZ:
     @classmethod
     def func(cls):
         do something
```

(or use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) if you prefer).